# Why does remapping a key in xkb (e.g. NMLK to Insert) affect other key (e.g. the Super key)?

Tags: keyboard

I changed the behavior of NumLock to perform as Insert with the following line added to my layout file ('br', could be 'us' etc.):

```
key <NMLK> {    [  Insert, Insert, Insert, Insert   ]   };
```

However, with this change, the Super key (aka Win key) stopped working.
Other functionalities like the change-brightness keys also stopped working.
This is not the first time I see such kind of interference between unrelated keys.

Is there a reason for it to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Using replace solved the problem:

```
replace key <NMLK> {    [  Insert   ]   };
```